# Basic Turtle Recursion

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have a quick question using Turtle with Python. I want the final drawing to look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFw5G.jpg

But my code only does a part of this, and I can't figure it out for the life of me. This is a homework assignment, so please don't do it for me, please just lead me in the right direction as I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. What exactly I can't figure out is how to make it reproduce the squares on the left side of the image, as it's only on the right.

Here is my code:

```
from turtle import *
differentColors = ['green', 'blue'] 
def jester(N, L): 
    if N <=0: 
        pass    
    else:       
       pencolor(differentColors[N % len(colors)])
       forward(L/2) 
       left(90)         
       forward(L)       
       left(90)         
       forward(L)   
       left(90)         
       forward(L)       
       left(90)         
       forward(L/2)         
       forward(L/2)         
       left(90)         
       forward(L)       
       right(150)       
       jester(N-1, L/2)                     

jester(4, 100)
```

thank you!

Comment: Please add your code as text, not an image. Some people don't have access to Imgur.

Comment: Besides people not having access to imgur, it's a lot easier to run your code if we don't have to type it in...

Comment: `from turtle import *

differentColors = ['green', 'blue']

def jester(N, L):
 if N <=0:
  pass
 else:
  pencolor(differentColors[N % len(colors)])
  forward(L/2)
  left(90)
  forward(L)
  left(90)
  forward(L)
  left(90)
  forward(L)
  left(90)
  forward(L/2)
  forward(L/2)
  left(90)
  forward(L)
  right(150)
  jester(N-1, L/2)
  

 
  
jester(4, 100)`

Comment: Please add your code in the post. The comment form erases all the newlines in the text you paste in.

Comment: Hint: if you want the square to have two ears, you need to call `jester` more than once inside the function.

Comment: But how do I flip it so it does the same thing on the left of all of the boxes? Sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the use of debugger helpful. Run your code as

```
import pdb
from turtle import *

differentColors = ['green', 'blue'] 
def jester(N, L):
    ...

pdb.run('jester(4, 10)')
```

First type `s` to **step into** the function, then type `n` for **next** to execute each line one by one, if you want to step into a recursive call to `jester` type `s` when you get to it. This should help you to see where your code is going wrong. Since your code is quite repetitive (turtle stuff nearly always is), you might want to add a few print statements to say what each section of the code is meant to be doing (like drawing the top side of the square, or getting into position for the recursive call).

Additional commands and more information about the python debugger can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Summary is `h` for help, `c` for continue and `u` to finish the current function call and go back up to the previous function. You can also see the value of a variable just by typing its name.

Comment: Okay, so I did that a few times, and it showed me step by step how my code was being executed. But I tried playing around with that a couple times, and I still cant get it to be symmetrical. I tried calling "jester" more than once and it just continues on that path.

Comment: The `jester` function is just a way of drawing squares in a pattern. Look at where each "ear" starts. You have to move the turtle to that position (and orientation) to be able to draw the ear in that position. Otherwise you will just end up drawing the ear right where the turtle currently is.